# Prove for symmetric real matrix $M$,$z^TMz>0$ for real vector $z$ for real implies it's true in complex

Tags: linear-algebra

For symmetric real matrix $M$, $z^TMz>0$ for real vector $z$, how to prove that it is also positive definite for $z\in C$?

Comment: If $M$ is real and $z$ are real, what does it mean to prove "positive definite in complex sense"?

Comment: Positive definite in the complex setting, I'm guessing, is $x^*Ax>0$ for every $x\in\mathbb C^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A$ is real symmetric and $x^TAx>0$ for every $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Let $z\in \mathbb C^n$. We can decompose $z=x+iy$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$.

Testing for positive-definiteness:

$z^*Az=(x^T-iy^T)A(x+iy)=x^TAx+y^TAy+i(x^TAy-y^TAx).$

Since $A$ is symmetric, $x^TAy=(x^TAy)^T=y^TA^Tx=y^TAx$.

Thus, $z^*Az=x^TAx+y^TAy>0$, by assumption.